# Complete discord bot say command

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

does anyone have a complete latest basic discord code with say command? Or anyone willing to teach me and guide me to make the bot. I'm dying to make one for my bot :'(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service and we expect you to have minimal knowledge of javascript / discord.js while working with it,

Although I'd help you go through your pain! Welcome to stackoverflow .

For starters let's require discord.js and initialise a [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: 4609 }); // This is intents bitfield value for DIRECT_MESSAGES, GUILD_MESSAGES and GUILD intents
```

Now let's set up our event listener for the [messageCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) so we can reply when an user messages, simultaneously we would define the prefix, command and user arguments

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: 4609 });
const prefix = "!"; 
client.on("messageCreate" ,  (message) => {
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/+ /); // defining what are arguments ( eg. !say hello, hello is our argument ) 
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();  // defining what a command is ( our first word to lowercase eg. !say hello then !say is our comamnd )
if(message.author.bot) return  // this is called botception, ignoring bot messages basically
if(command == "say") { // if the command is !say then repeat everything after the command 
message.reply(args.join(" ")); // eg. if user says !say hello welcome to stackoverflow, bot would reply with hello welcome to stackoverflow
message.delete(); // deleting the message from the user 
}
});
client.login("your_token_here");
```

Here are some useful resources for beginners to start up creating bots!

• [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/) 
• [Discord.js Beginners' Guide](https://discordjs.guide/)